# Glitch free frequency change on basic sinewave oscillator

Tags: c++, c, audio, signal-processing

I'm writing a basic sound lab to make experiments around audio generation using digital oscillators.

My oscillator works perfectly for a fixed frequency. However, in my program I have a slider to change frequency on the run. The frequency changes however, I can hear a small glitch everytime I switch the frequency. This is probably due to the abrupt frequency change.

I have written a control code to make my frequency change gradually until it reaches the desired frequency but something is not working correctly and I can't figure what.

Everytime a new frequency is set I determine the difference between the actual frequency and the new one. Then, I divide that difference for 44100 which is my sample rate, in order to have a second. I'm using a second to be able to understand the progress of the frequency change.

What happens is that I hear the frequency increasing but when it reaches the target frequency, the audible frequency seems to get down a bit. This is really awkward because if I output the value of the frequency that is being sent to the sinewave calculation, everything is just fine, no unexpected steps are being generated.

This is the code of the oscillator class. This frequency change control process is only working for an increasing frequency right now:

```
Oscillator::Oscillator(int freq, int sr):
    sampleIndex(0),
    chaseTargetFrequency(false),
    frequencyChanged(false)
{
    currentFrequency=freq;
    frequency=freq;
    sampleRate=sr;
}

void Oscillator::process(unsigned char* out)
{
    float t = qreal(sampleIndex % sampleRate) / sampleRate;

    if (frequencyChanged)
    {
        frequency+=inc;

        if (frequency>=currentFrequency)
        {
            frequencyChanged = false;
        }
    }

    qreal x = 0;

    // SINEWAVE
    x = 0.5f * qSin(2.f * M_PI * frequency * t);

    qint16 value = static_cast<qint16>(x * 32767);
    qToLittleEndian<qint16>(value, out);

    sampleIndex++;
}

void Oscillator::setFrequency(int value)
{
    if (frequencyChanged)
        return;

    currentFrequency = value;
    inc = (currentFrequency-frequency)/44000.f;
    frequencyChanged = true;
}
```

Does anybody as a clue of why this isn't working as expected? I hope my language was clear enough during the problem explanation.

Thanks in advance,

With my best regards,

Nuno Santos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glitch is because the output value changes instantaneously, because the input value to `sin` changes instantaneously when you change frequency.

To avoid this, ensure that your oscillator is *continuous phase*.  Rather than `sin(2.pi.f.t)`, do `sin(phi)`, where `phi += 2.pi.f.dt` (where `dt` is the step change in time).

Comment: Thx for your quick reply. Should dt be 1/44100? Can you point me to theory to better understand this phenomena?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "step change in time"